# Error running Cucumber JUnit: initializationError

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Using Java 1.8, Spring Boot, JUnit version 4.14

All of my colleges are able to run the Cucumber in the same project!

I am trying to run Cucumber tests and get the following exception:

> initializationError(com.nice.mcr.indexer.component_tests.TestRunnerUnitTests)
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;)V
> at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:89)

I have seen similar issues which in all of them the solution was a `pom.xml` versions mismatch. In my case, all the versions are the same:

```
    <cucumber.version>4.7.4</cucumber.version>
            
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                </dependency>
```

Can someone help me understand what the issue is?

Comment: What do you use to run Cucumber? If it's IDEA, clear your caches.

Comment: It didn't help! this is the IntelliJ version:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.6948.69, built on August 25, 2020
Licensed to NICE Systems Ltd. / Roy Leibovitz
Subscription is active until April 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Comment: Not a clue. Try using just maven and then triangulate till you can find out what is the difference that makes it fail for you.